# Sort members of a list of type enum by specific item

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an `enum`:

```
 public enum Fruits
    {
       Apple = 14,
       Lemon = 174,
       Grapes = 200,
       Peach = 1
    }
```

and a list by this `enum`:

```
IEnumerable<Fruits> Fruits = new List<Fruits>();
```

By default when I call `getValues` on the `enum` it sorts the entries by their id.
I show the list as a dropdown in the UI and want to sort the members of the list in specific order. In my sample I want `Lemon` to be the first item in the list.

I tried to order the items by the Lemon entry with something like this:

```
Fruits.OrderBy(f => f.Lemon);
```

but I am not allowed to do this `f.Lemon` in this context. Maybe I can `foreach` the list remove the Lemon item and then insert it as a first entry.

I am quite new to programming and I have found some similar questions but not with `enum` type.

Comment: In what kind of ordering is 'Lemon' the first? That doesn't make sense alphabetically or numerically.

Comment: Do you simply want `Lemon` first then arbitrarily sort (or don't sort) the other values? EDIT: And is this a permanent sorting or will you choose to have `Peach` first sometimes, `Grapes` other times and so on?

Comment: Yes, I just want Lemon first and arbitrarily sort (or don't sort) the other values. I think I need it to be permanent sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `OrderByDescending` + `ThenBy`:

```
fruits.OrderByDescending(f => f == Fruits.Lemon)
      .ThenBy(f => f);
```

Note that the variable should have a different name than the enum type (I've used lowercase `fruits`).

If you want to order second by the name:

```
      .ThenBy(f => f.ToString());
```

`f == Fruits.Lemon` returns a bool which you can order by. It's similar to SQL `CASE`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Lemon' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, FRUIT ASC
```